# Display the lowest average price of the year, along with the week number for that price, and the name of the month in which it occurred

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-processing

the problem was to load a file into a parallel arrays and then Display the lowest price and later the highest price of the year, along with the week number for that price, and the name of the month in which it occurred.
i was able to print out the lowest and highest price but i have been stuck at how to show the month and the day of that price
any help please..

this is my code

```
package `javaapplication98`;

     import java.io.File;

 import `java.io.FileNotFoundException;`
 import java.util.Scanner;



    public class JavaApplication98

{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 

    {
        File file= new File("D:\\Gas.txt");
        Scanner inputfile= new Scanner(file);

        String [] months= new String[35];
        String [] days= new String[35];
        int [] years= new int[35];
        double [] prices= new double[35];
        int index=0;
        double max=prices[0];


        while(inputfile.hasNext())
            {
                 months[index]=inputfile.next();
                 days[index]=inputfile.next();
                 years[index]=inputfile.nextInt();
                 prices[index++]=inputfile.nextDouble();      
            }
       for (int x=1; x<prices.length; x++)
           {
                 if (prices[x]>max)
                 max=prices[x];               
            }          
    System.out.println(max);   
    }

}
```

Comment: record the `index`

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable to store the current index of `max` in `prices`. Then, in the end when you have found the maximum value from the array, you will have its index.

You can access the month and day using the same index as the one you stored for `max`.

Comment: i created another variable to store the value of max but when i use it with the months or days it says lossy conversation because the types are not similar

Comment: You want to store the index of the max, which in your case is the value of x. So each time you say max = prices[x], you can also set maxIndex = x

Comment: im sorry if im bothering u please
but when i set the maxIndex =x then it will give me the  last value that x will take , which means it will not give me the  month that goes with the max price but it will give me the last month on my file

Comment: i got it ,, thank you so much,,,i actually had to aid the brackets to my if statement so it can gives me the corresponding value of index which is x

Comment: You only set maxIndex = x when you change max. In other words, set maxIndex = x only when prices[x] > max (inside your current if statement)

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
System.out.println(max)
```

That prints that maximum prize. Now you need to additionally remember the corresponding index! So you can do:

```
System.out.println(month[maxIndex] + " " + day[maxIndex] +.... )
```

In order to somehow print the date information instead.

Beyond that: please note that it is a bad idea to use "parallel" arrays. You should rather create a class that holds *all* of the values of one line ("row") of your file. And then have one array of such objects.

Comment: i was asked to do it with the parallel arrays that why
what about the maxIndex ,, do i need to creat another variable ?

Comment: i under and i do appreciate your answers my friend ,, but yes eventually ill do it the better and easy way